# Compare datetime year to current year in django template

Tags: python, django, datetime

I need to compare a year from object's `DateTime` field value with current year in my template. And if years are not same, show the object's year. This is how I am doing this:

```
{% now "Y" as current_year %}
    <ul>
        {% for news in news %}
            {% if news.date.year != current_year %}
                <b>{{ news.date.year }}</b>
                <li>{{ news }}</li>
            {% else %}
                <li>{{ news }}</li>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
```

And it is always true and displays me the year.
But if I use 2015 instead of `current_year` it works fine.

Basically I need to have this:

- First news!
- Second news!

  **2014**
- Third news!

  **2013**
- Fourth news!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it can be done the way you're trying to do it. But you can certainly write a method for your model which checks if the year is same.

```
from django.utils import timezone

class MyModel(...):
    # fields ...
    date = models.DateField(...)

    def was_published_this_year(self):
        return timezone.now().year == self.date.year
```

Now, in your templates do like this:

```
{% if not news.was_published_this_year %}
    Do something.
{% endif %}
```